# How to remove top and bottom percentile values when both categorical and numerical columns exist in R

Tags: r, dplyr, percentile, categorical

Consider data frame below

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("Y", "Y","N", "Y", "N", "N"),
                 b = c(200, 1,1.4,1.3,2,1.6),
                 c = c(200,-200,10,12,14,15),
                 d = c("f","f","m", "m","m","m"))
  a     b    c d
1 Y 200.0  200 f
2 Y   1.0 -200 f
3 N   1.4   10 m
4 Y   1.3   12 m
5 N   2.0   14 m
6 N   1.6   15 m
```

I want to trim data frame such that rows with values less than 1 percentile and greater than 99 percentile from the numeric columns are removed.

```
  a   b  c d
1 N 1.4 10 m
2 Y 1.3 12 m
3 N 2.0 14 m
4 N 1.6 15 m
```

I can remove top and bottom undesired values, when categorical variables are not present.

```
df %>% dplyr::select(is.numeric) %>%
    filter_all(all_vars(between(., quantile(., .01), quantile(., .99))))
```

but I do not know how to do the job while keeping categorical columns. any help or hint with is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `if_all` in `filter` and select the columns that are `numeric` with `where(is.numeric)`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(if_all(where(is.numeric),
     ~ between(.x, quantile(.x, .01), quantile(.x, .99))))
```

-output

```
  a   b  c d
1 N 1.4 10 m
2 Y 1.3 12 m
3 N 2.0 14 m
4 N 1.6 15 m
```

Comment: Why not df[findInterval(1:nrow(df), quantile(1:nrow(df),c(.01, 0.99)))==1,]?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to check for data type? you can filter by number of rows since it is a quantile.

```
df[findInterval(1:nrow(df), quantile(1:nrow(df),c(.01, 0.99)))==1,]
```